# replace text in richtext box quickly

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i'm trying to load a text file to richtextbox using this codes

```
 RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("path")
 RichTextBox1.LoadFile("path", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

but both of them take time to load the file ,, the file size is around 400-1MB 
so how to load it more quickly?

and with my code after loading the textfile i use this code

```
RichTextBox1.Text = Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "text", "othertext")
```

but the problem is this take alot of time !!
How to do it quickly and save time :) , thanks!

Comment: if you are simply working with it in code, then dont use a UI control as a variable

Comment: can you explain please ^_^ ?

Comment: (*if you are simply working with it in code*) == the program is working with it and there is no user to read the text; (*dont use a UI control as a variable*) == that RTB to hold the text

Comment: i tried but when i paste the texts directly to RTB  i found that not the full text is copied
i though thats because the maxlength but it was 2147483647 and cant make it high more

Comment: what about replacing part of text . do you know how to make it run quickly because its need around 2-5 mins to replace the lines , between i have around 13000 line

Answer (score 1):

You can cut the time almost in half by using an ordinary string variable instead of RichTextBox1.Text in the Replace function:

```
s = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("path")
s = s.Replace("text", "othertext")
RichTextBox1.Text = s
```

You can combine these into one or two statements, but separating them allows you time each operation. The time-consuming part is accessing the RichTextBox control.

Answer (score 1):

You could try reading it line-by-line:

```
Using Reader As New IO.StreamReader("<File Path>")
    Do Until Reader.EndOfStream
        Dim Line As String = Reader.ReadLine()
        Line = Replace(Line, "text", "othertext")
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Line & Environment.NewLine)
    Loop
End Using
```